# Is possible to boot Ubuntu with less than 128MB of RAM?

Tags: system-requirements

The machine I would like to install a working OS to is an old Toshiba Portege 3010ct notebook (Pentium 266 with 32MB EDO RAM and 4GB IDE hard drive). It's a quite slow and weak machine, but it's only needed for basic text editing, USB support (as it has 1x USB connector), and MP3 playing if it can handle that. The machine is flawless and is in working condition.

The BIOS it has is very basic and limited, and it can be only booted from either the hard drive or the floppy drive.. But here comes the twist : It does not have a floppy drive. It also lacks a CD-Rom, and it cannot boot from USB (no BIOS support). The only option is to boot from the hard drive. My only option to write to the hard drive is by removing it from the notebook, and plug it into my laptop via IDE to USB cable. I don't have a desktop machine to mount into as an internal hard drive.

I am really hoping that someone knows how to make a bootable os under these circumstances, as it can be very tricky to set up a hard drive on USB to work later on in IDE mode. I experimented with a lot of operating systems in the past few weeks (dos, win98, winxp, wary puppy (linux)), repartitioned and reformatted the hard drives many times for the specific needs of the different operating systems, rewrote the MBR if it was needed, but i done it all the time via USB, and i think that is the main problem. Because when i try to boot from the hard drive it is running as an internal IDE drive. I dont know what/how to edit manually so that an actual operating system would install from the hard drive to the hard drive, or better, if it can be installed manually (by copying the needed files, and it would simpy boot).

Any idea or solution is welcome!! :)

Answer (score 2):

With those specifications not even the lightest of the Ubuntu GUI-less distributions would work. Ubuntu needs at least 128MB of RAM and 3.5 GB of Hard Disk. You might try use PuppyLinux or DammSmallLinux and see if you have luck. I don't make promises.

Comment: You *never* do?

Comment: @Thomas Do what?

Comment: Make promises? :p